# Problem while using ViewPager

Tags: android, api, jar

I want to use ViewPager in my project. I tried to use code from this link http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html
and i included v4 jar file too. according to this code two class are missing

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

This there some thing wrong with the jar file or i m missing some thing while coding. Plz suggest

Answer (score 2):

Did you link the jar in your project?

Comment: yes i did that. it is able to import other files from jar. But these files are not there at all in jar. I m confused wheather there is prob with jar file ori have to include some other jar and where will i get it

Comment: from where can i download v2 and v4 jar files

Comment: you need to use the SDK updater: http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html